# Why could mean centering change results

Tags: regression, time-series, hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance

I used centering for my variables due to multicolleanirity and surprisingly the results (from before to after centering) changed for two interacted variables; one from significantly negative to significantly positive and the other from significantly positive to significantly negative.
I read that results normally change for the main effect, but not for the interaction.

> In my case the interaction results were changed >
>   What could be the reason and is this normal and what should I do?

I am doing panel data analysis with fixed effects 
 and here is my model

> Y it = β0 + β1 X1 it +β2 X2 it + β3 X3 it + β5 M it + β5 (X1 it × 2010 i) + β6(X2 it×2010i)+ β7 (X3 it × 2010 i)+ Year dummies + λi+ϵ it

M is the interaction variable and X are the independent variables ... when I run the model first, the VIF was too high and then whether I center or use z score the results change

Appreciate any feedback > thank you so much

Comment: Apparently `it` is a pair of subscripts, but what does `× 2010 i` mean?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what i and t are in your models, probably individual and time (in which case they should be subscripts). If they are individual and time, you might have dependent data, in which case you  will have to use a method that accounts for that (such as multilevel models).

However, one result of multicollinearity is that the parameter estimates are unstable - a tiny change in the input data can result in dramatic changes in the parameter estimates, including flips of signs and of significances. Belsley gives an example where changing the input data in the third or fourth significant figure makes huge changes in the results.

So, I would ignore the model with high collinearity.

You should also plot the data to see what is going on (always a good idea, especially with interactions) and check the substantive sense of your model.

Comment: If you have time, then you almost certainly do have dependent data; did you measure he same people more than once? As I said, colliner results are unstable, don't trust them.

Comment: I have 500 firms over five years financial data, but previous studies don't use multilevel unless the data for more than one country which is not my case.. what do you suggest

Comment: If it's the same 500 firms (or even if a lot of firms are repeated) then the data are dependent.

Comment: So do you suggest ignoring the model completely? or would multilevel analysis overcome the problem? and if yes, in my case what type exactly the multilevel would be? thanks a lot dear @Peter

Comment: There are two issues that are largely separate: 1) Collinearity. As I keep saying, the parameter estimates from a collinear model are unstable. Ignore them and do something else (centering, ridge regression, dropping variables, whatever). This would be so without any dependance in the data. 2) Dependance: This means you have violated an assumption of regression models and need to correct it. You can add a random intercept and possibly a random slope for each person.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15412/discussion-between-ben-and-peter-flom).